# Extracting a char from a string

Tags: java, android

I need to extract a char from a preset string. I know the method `string.charAt()`, I use it but it crash my program. The context that I use is the following :

```
private String values = "0123456789ABCDEFG";    

//Converts a 10 base number to a q base
private String t2q(String number, String base) {

    String a = Double.toString((int)(Double.parseDouble(number) / Double.parseDouble(base)));
    String b = Double.toString((int)(Double.parseDouble(number) % Double.parseDouble(base)));
    StringBuilder converted = new StringBuilder(a + b);
    if (!check_base(converted.toString(), base)) {
        return t2q(a, base) + values.charAt(Integer.parseInt(b));
    }
    char ab = values.charAt(Integer.parseInt(a));
    char ba = values.charAt(Integer.parseInt(b));
    return "" + ab + ba;
}
```

At the beginning i was thinking that my program crash because `a` is in a `Double` format e.g `1.0` so i use a function that transforms `1.0` in `1` but nothing, it still crashes. Also i tried with `Character` instead of `char` but it doesn't make a difference.
The Exception Error is "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int : "1.0"" for the example `number = "11011"` and `base = 16` , so `11011` in base `16` is `1B`.

Comment: what is "crashing" in terms of Exception? Divison by zero? Null Pointer?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: This function is used in a conversion base app. So when the program reach `char ab = values.charAt(Integer.parseInt(a));` instruction, i instantly get "Unfortunately, Base Calculator has stopped"

Comment: You haven't provided enough code for us to actually reproduce the problem. You're also still not providing the exception being encountered that's causing your application to crash.

Comment: @Jan so i used a 'try' and my Exception Error is "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int : "1.0""

Comment: Why, oh why, are you doing this using String parameters??? Change to `t2q(long number, int base)`!!!!!!!

Comment: @Andreas because how can you use long when are you dealing with 16 base numbers which include digits represented as characters ?

Comment: @CătălinMuntean But the **input** is a base 10 number, so .... a number. And the base is definitely a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't parse a String which represents a Double with Integer.parseInt().

This will not work:

```
Integer.parseInt("3.0");
```

This will work:

```
Integer.parseInt("3");
```

Use this instead:

```
new Double("3.0").intValue()
```

**But consider following behavior:**

`new Double("2.5").intValue()` will return 2.

Comment: @ProgWulf Ok, i have a question. I see that after doing this method `char ab = values.charAt(new Double(a).intValue()); for `a` being `1.0` , `ab` will be `'1' 49` what is that `49` ?

Comment: This 
char ab = values.charAt(new Double(a).intValue()); 
is returning only 1 in my case as expected.